# Primefaces how to update content in a dialog and keep the dialog centered?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a dialog that contains no content on page load and I'm dynamically setting the content of a dialog box based on the link that a user clicks on.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" id="dialog">
    <p:panel id="fullArticle">
        <h:outputText value="#{content.newsArticle}" escape="false" />
    </p:panel>
 </p:dialog>
...
...
<p:commandLink value="Read more" actionListener="#{content.getFullArticle}" onclick='dlg.show();' update=":fullArticle">
    <f:attribute name="contentId" value="#{news.contentId}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

The problem i'm having is that when you click the "Read More" link, it shows the dialog, but the dialog is not centered on the page. If i change the udpate attribute on the commandLink to `update=":dialog"`, the dialog flashes as if it's opening and then closing right away.

How can I update the dialog and have it be centered with dynamic content?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `onclick` is executed *before* the ajax request. You need to open the dialog in `oncomplete` instead. This will be executed *after* the ajax request and update. The `<p:dialog>` is namely by default hidden unless its `visible` attribute evaluates `true`.

```
<p:commandLink value="Read more" actionListener="#{content.getFullArticle}" 
    update=":dialog" oncomplete="dlg.show()">
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, are you aware that you can pass fullworthy objects as method arguments since EL 2.2? This makes the `<f:attribute>` and `actionListener` "hack" superfluous:

```
<p:commandLink value="Read more" action="#{content.getFullArticle(news)}" 
    update=":dialog" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
```

Comment: I'm running on tomcat 6 and that doesn't support the EL 2.2 does it?

Comment: Oh, it doesn't. But you could just install JBoss EL for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328

Comment: server guys won't buy that one here. I'll have to stick with attribute/actionlistener. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Bummer then. Even not when just in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/lib`? Anyway, no problem and you're welcome :)

Comment: why is there a `:` in `update=":dialog"` vs just saying `update="dialog"` without a `:` ?

Comment: @amphibient: usually, you don't put it in the same form for the reasons mentioned a.o. here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18958907 and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7372315

Comment: ok but i don't understand the function of the `:` notation, if you could explain that would be great (i would be happy to enter a separate question)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.
Updating the dialog makes it disappear and reappear (and forget its position).

To solve it, I created a wrapper tag around the dialog content.

```
<p:commandLink update=":playerViewDialogHeader,:playerViewDialogContent"
               oncomplete='playerViewDialogJS.show()' value='#{item.name}' />


<p:dialog id='playerViewDialog' widgetVar='playerViewDialogJS'>

   <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText id="playerViewDialogHeader" value="#{playerController.objectView.name}" />
   </f:facet>

   <h:form id='playerViewDialogContent'>
      <!-- CONTENT GOES HERE -->
   </h:form>

</p:dialog>
```