# RichFaces: TabPanel and param

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, tabpanel

Currently, i am dealing with rich:tabPanel in my web application based on JSF 2.0.
I encounter a very strange problem, which is related to my richface component.
Basically, i print some same stuff on each panel (here, it is a schedule table of a show, tab contains the day and content of tab contains the differents hours ).

Consequently, i have something like that:

```
<rich:tabPanel>
     <c:forEach items="#{show}" var="hour" ...>
       <rich:tab>
        <a4j:commandLink ...>
             <a4j:param value="hour.something" assignTo="#{bean.method}" />
        </a4j:commandLink>
     </ ..... >
```

When i click on the first commandlink, when my webpage is displayed, it's ok. But when i choose an other tab, and i click on the commandlink, the "bean.method" is not call. I need to click a second time to make the call of the function.

Finally, when i put the tabPanel as "switchtype=server", it works very well (without clicking 2 times).

But that's not the purpose, i want to use the client mode.
I see that on JIRA of richfaces v3, this problem has been solved [JIRA JBoss](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-175?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel). But there is no more information (except a comment but it's not working).

If anyone can help, it would be great.

Regards,

Comment: Need more info. Please tell us **1.** Where is your form? **2.** Don't you like to change the `switchType` to `ajax`?

Comment: There are 2 forms: The **first** surrounding the rich:tabpanel, the **second** surrounding the commandlink inside my rich:tab.  Changing the switchType with `ajax` doesn't change something, same thing occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using nested forms(form within form). This is not recommended in `JSF`. Even in `HTML` it is invalid. Remove one `form` and it will work.
Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/multiple-hform-in-a-jsf-page) too.

Comment: Working perfectly: I kept the form surrounding the rich:tabpanel and removed the other one. Again: thank you !

Comment: You are welcome. Note that if you want to prevent the full form being submitted when the `commandLink` is clicked, don't forget to add `ajaxSingle=true` to `<a4j:commandLink>`