# Why html <form> could not Render in the page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Jsf 2.x with Primefaces 3.5.

I used html form nested with JSF form like this.While rendering JSF form will be rendered.Normal Html Form could not render.

```
<h:form>
  <form>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
  </form>
<h:form>
```

I tried by setting id for all forms and set name also.

Answer (score 3):

Nesting forms concept in HTML is invalid. Even though you using `<h:form>` , ultimately renders like form inside a form in your scenario which is not valid approach. So, your code should be like

```
<h:form>
      <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
 </h:form>

<form action=".." method="post">

</form>
```

Check out BalusC answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/multiple-hform-in-a-jsf-page)