# JSF2 rendering xhtml page inside tabs (richfaces) doent work

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

We are working on JSF 2. 
We want an xhtml form to be displayed inside .
Using , it is displaying the contents of the XHTML file. 
But actions on command buttons are not working.

We have created tabs.xhtml page which is directed first through index.xhtml page. The code is as follows:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:tabPanel>
       <rich:tab name="Second">
           <ui:include  src="/Second.xhtml" />
       </rich:tab>
       <rich:tab name="Third">
        Here is tab #3
       </rich:tab>
     </rich:tabPanel>
</h:form>
```

In Second.xhtml, we have ADD NEW, EDIT, DELETE buttons whose actions are not working after being included in tabs.

Please Help.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: does your Second.xhtml contains `<h:form>` ? cause if it does you having nested forms (form inside form) which is baaaad... reorganize your pages so you wont have the nested forms (for example remove the form from Second.xhtml)

Comment: Create many side-to-side local forms, as Daniel suggests. Also, take a look at the advice on [Multiple h:form in a JSF Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/multiple-hform-in-a-jsf-page/7372315#7372315).

Comment: @Daniel Thanks.Its working using a4j:region instead of forms.

Answer (score 0):

Does your *Second.xhtml* contains `<h:form>` ?

Cause if it does you having *nested forms* (form inside form) which is *baaaad*... **reorganize** your pages so you won't have the nested forms

For example remove the form from *Second.xhtml*

[Here a bit more about nested forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7372315/617373)

Comment: We are working on JSF 2. 
Now, we are able to include xhtml page inside tabs. 
'But now switching among other tabs is a problem.

<rich:tabPanel>
     <rich:tab label="fst" name="First">
      <ui:include src="/FirstPage.xhtml" />
        </rich:tab>
  <rich:tab label="scnd" name="Second">
   This is second tab
  </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>

We are successfully able to see FirstPage.xhtml.
But cannot switch to Second tab.
Help me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: its a different question, check http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=tabPanel&sample=simple&skin=blueSky