# Nested forms in JSF

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

I am trying to use `<rich:tabPanel>` with form on each tab. Facelet looks like

```
      <h:form>
      <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">
        <rich:tab>
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Form1" />
          </f:facet>
      <ui:include src="form1.xhtml" />
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab>
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Form2" />
          </f:facet>
          <ui:include src="form2.xhtml" />              
        </rich:tab>
      </rich:tabPanel>
      </h:form>
```

`formX.xhtml` has it's own `ViewScoped` managed bean (formXBean) and typical syntax like

```
<ui:composition>
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{formXBean.show}">
    <h3>FormX list</h3>
    <h:form rendered="#{not empty formXBean.list}">
      <h:dataTable value="#{formXBean.list}" var="item">
        <h:column><f:facet name="header">field1</f:facet>#{item.subject}</h:column>
        <h:column><f:facet name="header">field2</f:facet>#{item.mload}</h:column>
        <h:column><f:facet name="header">actions</f:facet>
          <h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{formXBean.edit(item)}" />
          <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{formXBean.delete(item)}" />
        </h:column>
      </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty finalMarksBean.list}">
      <p>No records.</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:form>
      <center><p>
        <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{formXBean.add()}" />
      </p></center>
    </h:form>
  </h:panelGroup>
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{formXBean.edit}">
    // Add (edit) record form
  </h:panelGroup>
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{finalMarksBean.delete}">
    // delete record form
  </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

If I using formX.xhtml without placing into `rich:tab`, It works. When I include it into `rich:tab` - It doesn't work. I think, that nested forms is the reason, but how can I workaround it? Where can I find typical solution for this case?

Comment: You are right. You don't need nested `h:form`. You can use include without form inside.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple h:form in a JSF Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/multiple-hform-in-a-jsf-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use nested `h:form`. Remove `h:form` from included xhtml files. If you need wrapper for data, then you can use panel (for example `a4j:outputPanel`).