# What might serve as a logical NamingContainer in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2

Assume I have

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <div>
        <p:accordionPanel id="accordionPanel" multiple="false" >
            <div >
                <p:tab title="aTab">
                    <!--logical naming container tag open-->
                    <h:form>
                        <h:inputText id="inputText" value="#{backingBean.property}">
                            <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{backingBean.onChange}" render="@form ..:autoCompleteForm:autoComplete"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                    </h:form>
                    <h:form id="autoCompleteForm">
                        <p:autoComplete id="autoComplete" value="#{backingBean.property2}" disabled="#{backingBean.disabled}"/>
                    </h:form>
                    <!--logical naming container tag close-->
                </p:tab>
            </div>
        </p:accordionPanel>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

and I want to reference `autoComplete` relatively from the first form. According to http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.de/2009/02/jsf-working-with-component-ids.html a relative id specification is resolved relative to the closest naming container and to the closest naming container of the closest naming container if `..:` is specified. According to http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/ `Tab` isn't a `NamingContainer` (neither is `AccordionPanel`) which brings me in need of a logical naming container element which I imagine to put where the comments are in order to reduce complexity to a minimum for relative references. What would such a logical naming container be (I assmue that nested forms are not allowed ([Nested forms in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468460/nested-forms-in-jsf)))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the [`<f:subview>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/subview.html).

#### See also:

- [When to use f:view and f:subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883476/when-to-use-fview-and-fsubview/)