# Primefaces datatable duplicates data on deletion

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatables

im using hibernate 4, spring 4, lucene 3, primefaces 5, java 7.

I got a data table, which data is populated on the baking bean, the idea with the table is that it shows me some uncategorized words, and lets me categorizate them.

an example of the initial table looks normal for example

1 2 3 4 5

here is my page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" life="2000" />

    <p:dataTable id="words" var="word"
        value="#{wordCatalogatorController.unknownWords}" editable="true"
        style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <f:facet name="header">Row Editing</f:facet>

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
            listener="#{wordCatalogatorController.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
            listener="#{wordCatalogatorController.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" />

        <p:column headerText="Palabra">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{word.word}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:outputText value="#{word.word}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Tipo Palabra">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{word.wordType}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{word.wordType}" style="width:100%"
                        converter="#{wordTypeConverter}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{wordCatalogatorController.wordTypes}"
                            var="man" itemLabel="#{man.wordType}" itemValue="#{man}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width:32px">
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</html>
```

the bean for this is:

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class WordCatalogatorController {

    private List<Word> unknownWords = new ArrayList<Word>();

    private List<WordType> wordTypes = new ArrayList<WordType>();

    public WordCatalogatorController(){
        //inicializamos palabras desconocidas y tipos de palabras!
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
            unknownWords.add(new Word("" + i));
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
            wordTypes.add(new WordType("" + i));
        }

    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        Word currentWord = (Word) event.getObject();

        unknownWords.remove(currentWord);
    }

    public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Edit Cancelled",
                ((Word) event.getObject()).getWord());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

        if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                    "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
```

then after editing and saving the first row (1) the datatables updates with 1 2 2 3 4 5

Any ideas will be really apreciated!

here comes the code for pojo clases

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Word")
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "searchtokenanalyzer",tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
filters = {
  @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
  @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
  @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class,params = { 
      @Parameter(name = "ignoreCase", value = "true") }) })
      @Analyzer(definition = "searchtokenanalyzer")
public class Word {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long wordId;

    @Column(name="word")
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    @Analyzer(definition="searchtokenanalyzer")
    private String word;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="words")
    private Collection<Danger> dangers = new ArrayList<Danger>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="words")
    private Collection<Risk> risks = new ArrayList<Risk>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="words")
    private Collection<Control> controls = new ArrayList<Control>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "wordTypeId")  
    private WordType wordType;

    public Word(String word, WordType wordType) {
        super();
        this.word = word;
        this.wordType = wordType;
    }

    public Word(String word) {
        super();
        this.word = word;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Word){
            return ((Word)obj).getWord().equalsIgnoreCase(this.getWord());
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Word() {
        super();

    }

    public long getWordId() {
        return wordId;
    }

    public void setWordId(long wordId) {
        this.wordId = wordId;
    }



@Entity
@Table(name = "WordType")
@Indexed
public class WordType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long wordTypeId;

    @Column(name = "wordType")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @Analyzer(definition = "searchtokenanalyzer")
    private String wordType;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "wordType")
    private Set<Word> words;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!(obj instanceof WordType)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            WordType extenalWT = (WordType) obj;
            if (this.wordType.equalsIgnoreCase(extenalWT.getWordType())
                    && this.wordTypeId == extenalWT.getWordTypeId()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public WordType() {

    }

    public WordType(String wordType) {
        this.wordType = wordType;
    }

    public long getWordTypeId() {
        return wordTypeId;
    }

    public void setWordTypeId(long wordTypeId) {
        this.wordTypeId = wordTypeId;
    }

    public String getWordType() {
        return wordType;
    }

    public void setWordType(String wordType) {
        this.wordType = wordType;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Set<Word> getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public void setWords(Set<Word> words) {
        this.words = words;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return wordType;
    }

}
```

Comment: has it something to do with the id of the items in the datatable?

Comment: You have two nested forms(`form` and `form2`) there. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/multiple-hform-in-a-jsf-page.

Comment: I just made a simpler test and updated the code, and still doesn't work (It this one theres onlye one form).

Comment: Could you provide the code for Word and WordType classes?

Comment: Hi there, I was checking and it seams to be a primefaces bug, any way there goes the code (I updated on the main post) =)

Comment: The link to the primefaces issue is [link](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7460)

Comment: You added the issue twice? I guess you will have to wait for the issue to be resolved.

Comment: that's right, when I get some answer from them I'll be posting it here, also asked for a support quote from primefaces. Now the solution was to implement it using a SelectOneListbox inside a new dialog trigered on the cellSelected event, so far so good ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the best solution was to implement the select event for the data table, and in the event have a dialog to pick the option, then refresh the table, this is the final xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>


    <h:form id="myForm">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" life="2000" />


        <p:panel header="Sale Item" style="width: 400px;">

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <p:outputLabel value="Texto" for="acSimple" />
                <p:autoComplete id="acSimple"
                    value="#{wordCatalogatorController.texto}"
                    completeMethod="#{wordCatalogatorController.completeText}"
                    binding="#{wordCatalogatorController.autoCompleteText}" />

                <p:commandButton value="Guardar actividad" id="save"
                    update=":myForm:msgs words"
                    binding="#{wordCatalogatorController.saveButton}"
                    actionListener="#{wordCatalogatorController.saveActivity}"
                    styleClass="ui-priority-primary" process="@this" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:dataTable id="words" widgetVar="words" var="word"
                value="#{wordCatalogatorController.unknownWords}" editable="true"
                style="margin-bottom:20px" rowKey="#{word.word}"
                selection="#{wordCatalogatorController.selectedWord}"
                selectionMode="single" editMode="row">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                    listener="#{wordCatalogatorController.changeClient}"
                    oncomplete="PF('activityDialog').show()"
                    update=":myForm:activityDialog" />

                <f:facet name="header">Edicion de palabras</f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="Palabra">
                    <h:outputText value="#{word.word}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Edicion">
                    <h:outputText value="Presione para catalogar la palabra" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

        </p:panel>



        <p:dialog id="activityDialog" width="500px" height="600px"
            header="Palabra a catalogar: #{wordCatalogatorController.selectedWord.word}"
            widgetVar="activityDialog" modal="true" closable="false">

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

                <p:selectOneMenu id="wordTypes"
                    value="#{wordCatalogatorController.selectedWordType}"
                    style="width: 150px;" converter="#{wordTypeConverter}">
                    <p:ajax
                        listener="#{wordCatalogatorController.wordTypeChangeListener}"
                        update=":myForm:words" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{wordCatalogatorController.wordTypes}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>

        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this issue:

It seems to be an issue between the rowEditor and the table sorting. Having the correct update target on the ajax tag isn't an issue as the row is technically removed but the display gets messed up. You can get around this with just a touch of nastiness. You can force a filter during oncomplete for the ajax tag. This will get rid of the ghost duplicate record.

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" 
        listener="#{beanName.onRowEdit}" 
        update=":growl :messages :formName:tableId"
        oncomplete="PF('tableWidgetVar').filter();" />
```