# Richfaces Datatable loses submitted value of inputs on validation fail

Tags: validation, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I have two inputs - one inside a "normal" `h:dataTable` and one inside a `rich:dataTable` When I submit a wrong value, i.e. validation fails, the "normal" one keeps the value I submitted while the second one loses it. See the following code snippets (enter any value an press the button):

#### ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -484022507596298941L;

    private String[] stringArray1 = {"Element 1", "Element 2"}; // + Getter
    private String[] stringArray2 = {"Element A", "Element B"}; // + Getter
    private Map<String, String> inputValues = new HashMap<String, String>(4); // + Getter

    public TestController() {
        inputValues.put(stringArray1[0], "");
        inputValues.put(stringArray1[1], "");
        inputValues.put(stringArray2[0], "");
        inputValues.put(stringArray2[1], "");
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Did something");
    }

    public void validate(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("This can never be valid."));
    }
}
```

#### View

```
<h:form>
    <h1>h:dataTable</h1>
    <h:dataTable id="table1" value="#{testController.stringArray1}" var="string" columnClasses="inactive">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{string}:"/>
            <h:inputText id="someInput" value="#{testController.inputValues[string]}" validator="#{testController.validate}"/>
            <h:message for="someInput" id="msg" style="color: red;"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h1>rich:dataTable</h1>
    <rich:dataTable id="table2" value="#{testController.stringArray2}" var="string">
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{string}:"/>
            <h:inputText id="someInput" value="#{testController.inputValues[string]}" validator="#{testController.validate}"/>
            <h:message for="someInput" id="msg" style="color: red;"/>
        </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>

    <h:commandButton id="button" action="#{testController.doSomething}" value="do something"/>
</h:form>
```

Is this known Richfaces behaviour or a bug of some kind? Is there a way to make it behave the same way the normal JSF-DataTable does? Using `h:dataTable` instead is not always an option and losing your "I-was-just-about-to-correct-it" input is rather annoying.

ADDITION:
I just checked the behaviour of ui:repeat and a4j:repeat and it's just the same: ui:repeat keeps the submitted value while a4j:repeat does not.

UPDATE: Re-worked example code to rule out some possible problems as mentioned in comments (input fields now point to different values; only one form element).

Tested on Mojarra 2.1.21 with RichFaces 4.3.7 and JBoss AS 7 plus on Mojarra 2.2.7 with RichFaces 4.5.0 Alpha3 and JBoss Wildlfy - same result.

Comment: are you using it like this? two forms in the same page?

Comment: Yes, one for general navigation, one for a user-provided input.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried each `form` of your page separately with Richefaces 4.3.7 and Mojarra 2.2.6 and it's perfectly working! i didn't noticed any abnormal behavior, when validation fails i didn't lost any values. That means that there is no Validation issues with the Richfaces components.

However, When using the two forms in a single page, i can notice that when i submit the first form the `inputText` of the second form loses it's value, while if we submit the `form2` the `inputText` of the first form don't lost it's value, in my guess its because JSF stored the state of it's HTML components in the `javax.faces.ViewState` and doesn't do the same for Richfaces components, using `Firebug` you can easily verify that the only common `request parameter` between those two POST requests is the `javax.faces.ViewState`.

Comment: When reading this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/multiple-hform-in-a-jsf-page I get the impression that is should be OK to have two forms in parallel. Probably the problem is that both forms operate on the same value.

Comment: @cheffe Yes, regarding BalusC's answer there is no problem on using parallel forms. But, the issue is not du to using the same value as I tested that with tow different values but I got the same behavior

Comment: I tested this locally with one form at a time, same problem. I do not have your Mojarra version, I will check this next.

Comment: @Louise which version do you have ?

Comment: From what I can tell 2.1.21. Comes with a JBoss AS 7

Comment: Ok, i don't see any incompatibily reason, please let me know once you tried another Mojarra version

Comment: See updates on question. I reduced the example to one form. We ran it in a different project with Mojarra 2.2.7 and saw the same behaviour. I currently stepping through some more under the hood code, but I'm still rather lost.

Comment: Wich browsers are you using to test that ?

Comment: Usually Chrome. Just checked in Firefox and IE8 - same behaviour.

Comment: Don't know if that's how this is done around here, but I rewarded the bounty for your efforts before it expires.

Comment: @Louise me too I don't know how the bounties work. However, I still doubt some state saving issue, could you try adding  `<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>` to your `web.xml`

Comment: @Louise so from Michal Petrov's answer seems I'm right on the state saving issue ;) and thanks that you tracked that issue and you updated us