# How to update a panel using a button from another page: primefaces

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces

i am creating a simple shopping cart application. In this, when the user selects an item from the panel and clicks the add to cart button outside the panel, the items must be displayed in the datagrid. But unfortunately i am not able to achieve it. 
index.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<f:view>
    <h:head>
        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content">
                <ui:include src="/resources/templates/template.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="index">
            <br />
            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
            <p:tabView orientation="top" id="panel">



                <p:tab title="Men" id="men">
                    <h:panelGrid id="MenPanel">
                        <ui:include src="/men1.xhtml"></ui:include>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Women" id="women">
                    <h:panelGrid id="WomenPanel">
                        <ui:include src="/women1.xhtml"></ui:include>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>

            </p:tabView>


            <br />


            <p:commandButton value="Add to Bag" update="dlg2" process="panel"
                oncomplete="PF('dlg2').show()" />


            <p:dialog header="Bag" modal="true" showEffect="clip"
                widgetVar="dlg2" id="dlg2" resizable="false" width="300"
                height="200">
                <p:outputPanel id="bag">
                    <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{itemDataBean.userselectedItems}">
                        <p:column headerText="Item Id">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.itemid}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText=" Item Name">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Item Price">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.price}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Item Price">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.size}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>


            <p:commandButton value="Checkout" update="dlg2"
                oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" />
            <p:dialog header="Cart" modal="true" showEffect="clip"
                widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" width="500" height="500" id="dlg">
                <p:outputPanel id="cart">
                    <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{itemDataBean.cartlist}">
                        <p:column headerText="Item Id">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.itemid}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText=" Item Name">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Quantity">
                            <h:outputText value="1" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Item Price">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.price}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:columnGroup type="footer">
                            <p:row>
                                <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right"
                                    footerText="Total Price:" />
                                <p:column footerText="#{itemData.total}" />

                            </p:row>
                        </p:columnGroup>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

men1.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="MenItemForm" prependId="false">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <p:outputLabel value="Select Category : ">
                    <br />
                </p:outputLabel>
            </p:outputPanel>
            <p:selectManyCheckbox id="shopmen" value="#{itemDataBean.selectedMenItems}">
                <br />
                <f:selectItems value="#{itemDataBean.menItems}" var="item"
                    itemValue="#{item.itemid}" itemLabel="#{item.name}" />
                <br />

            </p:selectManyCheckbox>
            <br />
            <br />
</h:form>
```

Women1.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="womenItemForm" prependId="false">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <p:outputLabel value="Select Category : ">
                    <br />
                </p:outputLabel>
            </p:outputPanel>
            <p:selectManyCheckbox id="shopwomen" value="#{itemDataBean.selectedWomenItems}">
                <br />
                <f:selectItems value="#{itemDataBean.womenItems}" var="item"
                    itemValue="#{item.itemid}" itemLabel="#{item.name}" />
                <br />

            </p:selectManyCheckbox>
            <br />
            <br />
        </h:form>
```

and the bean class:

/**
 * Class to get the data for the UI 
 */

```
package com.shop.web;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import com.shop.data.Item;

/**
 * @author svalsalan
 *
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "itemDataBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ItemDataBean {
    private List<Item> MenItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private List<Item> WomenItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private List<Item> Items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    public List<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> selectedMenItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> selectedWomenItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<Item> userselectedItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    List<Item> Cartlist = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        Items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        // set an initial value for the price

        // Create items
        Item Shirt = new Item(1, "Shirt", 100, "S");
        Shirt.setItemid(1);
        Item tshirt = new Item(1, "T-Shirt", 200, "M");
        tshirt.setItemid(2);
        Item jean = new Item(1, "Jeans", 300, "L");
        jean.setItemid(3);
        Item Dress = new Item(0, "Dress", 300, "S");
        Dress.setItemid(4);
        Item Tops = new Item(0, "Tops", 100, "S");
        Tops.setItemid(5);
        Item skirt = new Item(0, "Skirt", 200, "S");
        skirt.setItemid(6);
        // Add them to the list
        Items.add(0, Shirt);
        Items.add(1, tshirt);
        Items.add(2, jean);
        Items.add(3, Dress);
        Items.add(4, Tops);
        Items.add(5, skirt);
        return Items;
    }

    /**
     * @return the menItems
     */
    public List<Item> getMenItems() {
        MenItems.clear();
        getItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.size(); i++) {
            if (Items.get(i).getCategoryId() == 1) {
                MenItems.add(Items.get(i));
            }
        }
        return MenItems;
    }

    /**
     * @return the womenItems
     */
    public List<Item> getWomenItems() {
        WomenItems.clear();
        getItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.size(); i++) {
            if (Items.get(i).getCategoryId() != 1) {
                WomenItems.add(Items.get(i));
            }
        }
        return WomenItems;

    }

    /**
     * @param menItems
     *            the menItems to set
     */
    public void setMenItems(List<Item> menItems) {
        MenItems = menItems;
    }

    /**
     * @param womenItems
     *            the womenItems to set
     */
    public void setWomenItems(List<Item> womenItems) {
        WomenItems = womenItems;
    }

    /**
     * @return the items
     */

    /**
     * @param items
     *            the items to set
     */
    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        Items = items;
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedMenItems() {
        return selectedMenItems;

    }

    /**
     * @return the selectedWomenItems
     */
    public List<String> getSelectedWomenItems() {
        return selectedWomenItems;
    }

    /**
     * @param selectedMenItems
     *            the selectedMenItems to set
     */
    public void setSelectedMenItems(List<String> selectedMenItems) {
        this.selectedMenItems = selectedMenItems;
        System.out.println(selectedMenItems);
    }

    /**
     * @param selectedWomenItems
     *            the selectedWomenItems to set
     */
    public void setSelectedWomenItems(List<String> selectedWomenItems) {
        this.selectedWomenItems = selectedWomenItems;
        System.out.println(selectedWomenItems);
    }

    /**
     * @return the selectedItems
     */
    public List<String> getSelectedItems() {

        this.selectedItems.clear();
        selectedItems.addAll(getSelectedWomenItems());
        selectedItems.addAll(getSelectedMenItems());
        return selectedItems;
    }

    /**
     * @param selectedItems
     *            the selectedItems to set
     */
    public void setSelectedItems(List<String> selectedItems) {
        this.selectedItems = selectedItems;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userselectedItems
     */
    public List<Item> getUserselectedItems() {

        this.userselectedItems.clear();

        // loop through the selectedItems array
        for (String str : selectedItems) {

            // each one item in the array, loop throug the list from
            // getMenItem()
            for (Item item : Items) {

                // Match the ids' and store in a different list
                if (str.matches(Integer.toString(item.getItemid()))) {
                    // add the items to the new list
                    this.userselectedItems.add(item);
                }
            }
            // return the new list
        }

        return this.userselectedItems;
    }

    /**
     * @param userselectedItems
     *            the userselectedItems to set
     */
    public void setUserselectedItems(List<Item> userselectedItems) {
        this.userselectedItems = userselectedItems;
    }

    /**
     * @return the selectedMenItems
     */

    /**
     * @return the cartlist
     */
    public List<Item> getCartlist() {
        Cartlist.clear();

        Cartlist.addAll(getUserselectedItems());

        return Cartlist;
    }

    /**
     * @param cartlist
     *            the cartlist to set
     */
    public void setCartlist(List<Item> cartlist) {
        Cartlist = cartlist;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userselectedMenItems
     */
    public int getTotal() {
        int total = 0;

        for (Item totalItemPrice : getCartlist()) {
            total += totalItemPrice.getPrice();
        }
        return total;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed here is that you should avoid nesting forms(see here: [How to use <h:form> in JSF page? Single form? Multiple forms? Nested forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/using-multiple-hform-in-a-jsf-page))

For your question in updating the a specific portion in your html, it generally goes like

```
update=":name_of_containing_form:id_of_element_to_update"
```

Comment: Another issue was that i was not calling the 'getSelectedItems()' within getUserselectedItems() method.