# Action Listener in component not working

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

- JVM 1.8.0_144
- JSF 2.2.14 (Mojarra)
- PrimeFaces 6.1.4

The root cause is that a *p:dialog* in the component not appending to HTML body properly.

To the best of my knowledge this example should append the form with the ID of *uspsRecommendedAddressDlg* that is in the component to the end of the document yet it remains inside the outer form. In a fully fleshed out version this prevents an *actionListener* in a *commandButton* from being executed.

The main JSF page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:my_cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/components"
    >
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <p class="center">Test Address Validation</p>

        <p:panel>
            <h:form id="addressForm" name="addressForm" prependId="false">
                <my_cc:bareBones />
            </h:form>
        </p:panel>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:component
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>

    <cc:interface name="bareBones" displayName="bareBones" shortDescription="Address Collector">
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <p:dialog
            id="uspsRecommendedAddressDlg"
            widgetVar="uspsRecommendedAddressDlg"
            modal="true"
            appendTo="@(body)"            
            header="Header"
            position="300, 100"
            closable="false"
        >

            <h:form id="selectAddressDlgForm" prependId="false">
                <p:outputPanel id="selectAddressPanel">

                    <div class="singleRow">
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                    </div>

                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

The generated HTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
<head id="j_idt2">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/my-internal/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-afterwork" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/my-internal/javax.faces.resource/fa/font-awesome.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.1.4" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/my-internal/javax.faces.resource/components.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.1.4" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/my-internal/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.1.4"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/my-internal/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.1.4"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/my-internal/javax.faces.resource/core.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.1.4"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/my-internal/javax.faces.resource/components.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.1.4"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/my-internal/javax.faces.resource/validation/validation.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.1.4"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/my-internal/javax.faces.resource/validation/beanvalidation.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.1.4"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">if(window.PrimeFaces){PrimeFaces.settings.locale='en';PrimeFaces.settings.validateEmptyFields=true;PrimeFaces.settings.considerEmptyStringNull=false;}</script>
    </head>
<body>

    <p class="center">Test Address Validation</p>
    <div id="j_idt5" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-widget="widget_j_idt5">
        <div id="j_idt5_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content">
            <form
                id="addressForm"
                name="addressForm"
                method="post"
                action="/my-internal/secure/test/test_validate_address.jsf"
                enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            >
                <input type="hidden" name="addressForm" value="addressForm"/>

                <h1>Content</h1>
                <div
                    id="j_idt6:uspsRecommendedAddressDlg"
                    class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container"
                >
                    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-top">
                        <span id="j_idt6:uspsRecommendedAddressDlg_title" class="ui-dialog-title">
                            Header
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
                        <form
                            id="j_idt6:selectAddressDlgForm"
                            name="j_idt6:selectAddressDlgForm"
                            method="post"
                            action="/my-internal/secure/test/test_validate_address.jsf"
                            enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                        >
                            <input
                                type="hidden"
                                name="j_idt6:selectAddressDlgForm"
                                value="j_idt6:selectAddressDlgForm"
                            />
                            <div
                                id="j_idt6:selectAddressPanel"
                                class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget"
                            >

                                <div class="singleRow">
                                    <h2>Title</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input
                                type="hidden"
                                name="javax.faces.ViewState"
                                id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"
                                value="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"
                                autocomplete="off"
                            />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script
                    id="j_idt6:uspsRecommendedAddressDlg_s"
                    type="text/javascript"
                >$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("Dialog","uspsRecommendedAddressDlg_j_idt6",{id:"j_idt6:uspsRecommendedAddressDlg",modal:true,appendTo:"@(body)",position:"300, 100"});});</script>
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="javax.faces.ViewState"
                    id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:1"
                    value="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"
                    autocomplete="off"
                />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script id="j_idt5_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("Panel","widget_j_idt5",{id:"j_idt5"});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked. Even IF it should be moved, it may initially still not be nested in another form.

Comment: I added some additional text to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/how-to-use-hform-in-jsf-page-single-form-multiple-forms-nested-forms making this Q a 'duplicate'.

Comment: off-topic:  don't use  `prependId="false"`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/uiform-with-prependid-false-breaks-fajax-render. Might even be that this breaks part of the behaviour too

Comment: The dialog and form are in a component and therefore can't avoid being nested in another form. I thought that was the whole point of the appendTo="@(body) was to move the dialog and it's form outside the parent form.

Comment: No its intention is to move it to a place where it can be properly displayed (z-index wise e.g. for modality). It always has to be concorm html specifications before manipulating the Dom. And you can avoid it being nested in another firm by moving it out of the parent form initially. I have never encountered a situation where this was not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support @Kukeltje!

Ultimately the answer is to structure components so they do not have embedded forms. Let the form come from the surrounding JSF document.

Comment: So you mase a 'god' form?

Comment: I suppose that depends on the definition of a "god" form. The main page can have as many forms as it needs. The composite component needs to reside inside one of them. It cannot stand alone.

Comment: Ok, no that is(are) not a god-form(s). A god form is e.g. the first child inside the `<h:body>`, ending right before the `</h:body>` in the main template...