# f:ajax wont render h:panelGroup

Tags: ajax, jsf

this is the code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{recBean.permission()}"/>
</f:metadata>
    <h:head>

               <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css"></link>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
        <title>Reclamation</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <b:navBar brand="Reclamations" brandHref="ReclamationAll.xhtml" >
  <b:navbarLinks>
   <b:navLink value="Etats des Reclamation" href="InterventionAll.xhtml"></b:navLink>
    <b:navLink value="Contrat" href="ContratAll.xhtml"></b:navLink>
    <b:navLink value="La liste de nos produit" href="produitAll.xhtml"></b:navLink>
  </b:navbarLinks>
</b:navBar>


        <f:view>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function success() {
                  toastr.success("Réclamation ajouté avec success !");
              }

</script> 

            <h:form>

                <h1><h:outputText value="Reclamation"/></h1>
                <h:panelGroup id="result">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2" >


                    <h:outputLabel value="Client:" for="client" />

                    <b:selectOneMenu  id="client" value="#{sessionScope.idcli}" disabled="#{sessionScope.idcli==null ? false : true }" >

                        <!-- fixed -->

                        <f:selectItems value="#{recBean.clientSelect}"  />

                    </b:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Produit:" for="produit" />
                    <b:selectOneMenu id="produit" value="#{recBean.idproduit}" >
                        <!-- fixed -->
                        <f:selectItems value="#{recBean.produitSelect}" />

                    </b:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Nom De Reclamation" for="descCli" />
                    <b:inputText id="nomRec" value="#{recBean.rec.nomRec}" title="Nom De Reclamation" required="true" requiredMessage="The DescCli field is required."/>

                   <h:outputLabel value="DateCreRec:" for="dateCreRec" />
                   <b:dateTimePicker id="dateCreRec" show-date="true" mode="toggle-icon"   required="true" use-current="true" value="#{recBean.rec.dateCreRec}"/>



                    <h:outputLabel value="TypeRec:" for="type"/>                        
                        <h:selectOneRadio  id ="type" value="#{recBean.type}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="réclamation logiciel" itemLabel="Reclamation Logiciel"></f:selectItem>


                            <f:selectItem  itemValue="réclamation technique" itemLabel="Reclamation technique"></f:selectItem>

                        </h:selectOneRadio>
                    <h:outputLabel value="DescCli:" for="descCli" />
                    <b:inputTextarea id="descCli" value="#{recBean.rec.descCli}" title="DescCli" required="true" requiredMessage="The DescCli field is required."/>




                     <h:outputLabel value="DegUrgence:" for="degUrgence" />


                     <b:selectOneMenu id="degUrgence" value="#{recBean.degreurgence}" >
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel=""></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="urgente"></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="très urgente"></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="pas urgente"></f:selectItem>

                    </b:selectOneMenu>



                </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                 <b:form horizontal="true">
                    <b:commandButton  value="Ajouter" action="#{recBean.ajouter()}" onclick="success();" >

                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="result"  />
                    </b:commandButton>

                    <b:commandButton value="retourner a la liste " action="ReclamationAll.xhtml"/> 
                    </b:form>

            </h:form>
        </f:view>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

i puted a panelGrid into panelGroup hoping to render the panel group id with the commandButton using ajax render 
and i get this error when i open the page :

> message Invalid search expression: result The subexpression result
>   doesn't exist, or it can't be resolved.
>   net.bootsfaces.component.commandButton.CommandButton
>   j_idt11:j_idt33:j_idt34 Additional information: ID not found: result
>   search expression: result

Am I doing something wrong here? Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Can you please make sure your code is well formatted and indented. Oh and nested forms are not allowed in html

Comment: okay i will put full page

Comment: @Kukeltje Done !

Comment: can you explain more about the nested forms or give me a solution

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=nested+forms+not+allowed+html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/how-to-use-hform-in-jsf-page-single-form-multiple-forms-nested-forms and please create a [mcve] for your question...

Comment: all the problem was in the nested form thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use <h:form> in JSF page? Single form? Multiple forms? Nested forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/how-to-use-hform-in-jsf-page-single-form-multiple-forms-nested-forms)