# primefaces selectonemenu on change event not working

Tags: ajax, primefaces, dropdown, selectonemenu

i've been dealing with this for a quite some time already. When i choose an item in selectOneMenu i want to update another selectOneMenu with specific values and it is not working.

xhtml:

```
<p:dialog id="noviTermin_dlg" header="Upisi podatke o terminu" widgetVar="termin_dlg" modal="true"
        height="250" width="500">
        <h:panelGroup id="noviTerminPanel">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Pacijent:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="pacijentiList" value="#{termini.selectedPacijent}" 
                    filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <p:ajax listener="#{termini.writeSomething}"
                        update="bolestiList" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Odaberi pacijenta" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{termini.pacijenti_list}" var="pacijent"
                        itemLabel="#{pacijent.pacijent_prezime} #{pacijent.pacijent_ime}"
                        itemValue="#{pacijent}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="Bolest:" />
               <p:selectOneMenu id="bolestiList" value="#{termini.selectedBolest}"
                    filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" disabled="#{empty selectedPacijent}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Odaberi bolest" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{termini.bolesti_list}" var="bolest"
                        itemLabel="#{bolest.naziv_bolesti}"
                        itemValue="#{bolest}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputText value="Vrijeme pocetka:" />
                <pe:timePicker mode="popup" />
                <h:outputText value="Vrijeme kraja:" />
                <pe:timePicker mode="popup" />
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="Spremi" icon="fa fa-save"
                        process="noviTerminPanel"
                        update="table_termini"
                        oncomplete="PF('termin_dlg').hide();"></p:commandButton>
                </f:facet>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:dialog>
```

ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="termini")
@ViewScoped
public class TerminiBean implements Serializable{

    private List<Pacijenti> pacijenti_list;
    private Pacijenti selectedPacijent;
    private List<PovijestBolesti> bolesti_list;
    private PovijestBolesti selectedBolest;
    //+get set

   public void writeSomething() {
    System.out.println("adasd");
}
```

Converter:

```
    @FacesConverter(forClass=Pacijenti.class)
public class PacijentiConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
                    return null;
                }

                try {
                    Pacijenti pac = new Pacijenti();
                    for(Pacijenti p : CommonServices.fetchPacijentiFromDB()) {
                        if(value == p.getPacijent_id()) {
                            pac = p;
                        }
                    }
                    return pac;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(value + " is not a valid Warehouse ID"), e);
                }
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid theme."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (value instanceof Pacijenti) {
            return String.valueOf(((Pacijenti) value).getPacijent_id());
        } else {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(value + " is not a valid Warehouse"));
        }
    }
}
```

In this example i am just trying to write something in console when i click on item in selectOneMenu.

Note: I've only posted code that is relevant to this problem.

Comment: Try to wrap your view inside a <h:form> as in the primefaces example https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml

Comment: Entire body is inside <h:form>.

Comment: @Ovoxo Also, isnt it curious that even showcase isnt working?

Comment: The showcase 'does not work', but if you _**debug**_, you'll see a a response coming back in the network tab that does contain the right cities. So only the ui part is not updated. What is your PF version?

Comment: 6.2, I tried switching to older versions and it's still the same.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of problems with dialogs containing event handling or other overlay components in one single big main form i ended up with the following pattern: **Separate forms** for separate components. One form per dialog. Dialog embedded in form.

Your event notation looks ok and should IMHO work.
In case the event works and the update doesn't: You could also try to update parents instead of input components (for example @form or @parent or noviTerminPanel.

Good Luck.

Comment: 'God' forms are evil... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/how-to-use-hform-in-jsf-page-single-form-multiple-forms-nested-forms

Comment: @Kukeltje - yes, that's why I've recommended to not use one. Also posting the whole form is the default (unless you're not working with process and/or partial processing), which is bad practice the bigger a JSF application gets.

Comment: ;-), I should have posted:  'God' forms are _**indeed**_ evil (I was agreeing with you)

Comment: Still no success. I tried switching to simple text selectItem values and it works but that's not really what i need...

Comment: Strange. Perhaps you want to test simpler selections to find the problem: Just a plain page with a plain selection, two fix entries, without and with dialog. Or just a javascript "console.log" for "oncomplete" in the p:ajax. Have you checked the javascript console for errors? Javascript may stop working in the page when an error occurs.