# Execute other form field value in JSF ajax

Tags: forms, jsf, submit

Consider the following JSF 2.x markup:

```
<h:form id="form1">

    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{testBacking.input}"/> 

</h:form>


<h:form id="form2">

    <h:commandButton value="go" action="#{testBacking.go()}">
        <f:ajax execute="@all" render="output"/>
    </h:commandButton>               
    <h:outputText id="output" value="#{testBacking.input}"/>

</h:form>
```

The action method as follows:

```
public void go() {
        System.out.println("go() is called");
         System.out.println("input: "+ input);
    }
```

The input value does not submitted to the server upon clicking the button.

Are there any ways to submit the input value to the server (while keeping the input in a different form)?

If you can only submit fields from the same form, then what is the different between the following two?

```
<f:ajax execute="@all" render="output"/>
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="output"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search of `jsf execute=@all vs execute=@form` yields some results:

- [JSF: Execute values of multiple forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638103/jsf-execute-values-of-multiple-forms)
- [What is <f:ajax execute="@all"> really supposed to do? It POSTs only the enclosing form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999101/jsf-2-0-with-fajax-execute-all)

In essence, the JSF processing works ok but HTML only sends the form that contains the ajax (I suspect HTML specifies a separate request for each form).

Comment: Basically the @all parameter in ajax tag seems meaningless.