# in primefaces how to scan for multiple components

Tags: primefaces, components

In one of the blogs i saw that the components can be scanned in the ajax call, i'd like to know how to scan for multiple components using p:component method

```
<p:ajax listener="#{providerSelectBean.onRowSelect}"  
update=":#{p:component('output')}" event="rowSelect"/>
```

Thanks & Appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best off using a PrimeFaces Selector

```
update="@(.ui-panel)"
```

This would update anything that has .ui-panel as a class, refer to http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf

[How do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work)
Gives a good example aswell

And: [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)