# Exclude Component from Process jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Xhtml Page using Primefaces component and jsf im building my page with one form

```
     <h:form id="form">
         <p:tabView id="tab">
             <p:tab title="Thème de la formation" >
                  <ui:include src="include/tabThemeFormation.xhtml" >
                     <ui:param name="ficheFormaCtrl" value="#{editFormCatalogueFormationController}"/>
                            </ui:include>
                        </p:tab>
                 <p:tab title="Fiche Formation" >
                    <ui:include src="include/tabFicheFormation.xhtml" >
                        <ui:param name="ficheFormaCtrl" value="#editFormCatalogueFormationController}"/>
                            </ui:include>
                 </p:tab>
  <a:row>  
                    <p:commandButton value="#{bundleCommun.btn_valider}" action="#{editFormCatalogueFormationController.edit()}"   icon="fa fa-check-square-o" ajax="false" disabled="#{editFormCatalogueFormationController.disabled}"/> 
                    <p:commandButton value="#{bundleCommun.btn_retour}" immediate="true" action="listFormCatalogueFormation" icon="fa fa-reply" styleClass="GrayButton" ajax="false"  />
                </a:row>
            </h:form>
```

i want to exclude the seconde tab from the process help me thanx

> Ps: I try this it's doesn't work for me

[How to exclude child component in ajax update of a parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614882/how-to-exclude-child-component-in-ajax-update-of-a-parent-component)

Comment: Try excluding the **content** of the second tab.

Comment: What do you mean with "I want to exclude the secod tab"? Couldn't you use `rendered="false"`?

Comment: "I want to exclude the second tab" it's mean i want to process the  first  tab with my commandButton  and exclude the second tab

Comment: You can check this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855294/primefaces-update-only-selected-tab