# Exclude inner component from a table, updating it on primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces 3.5 and I have a page with a p:datatable and a rowexpansion that holds a panelGrid including an inputText and a command button.I have also an external add button.
The page is like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{backbean.values}" >
<p:column>
  Some value.....
</p:column>
<p:column>
  Some value.....
</p:column>
<p:rowExpansion>
<p:panel>
      <p:panelGrid id="grid" styleClass="grid">
              MyInput Text.......
              <p:commandButton value="confirm" actionListener="# {backbean.listener}" update="grid"
      </p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
</p:rowExpansion>
<p:commanButton value="add" actionListener="#{backbean.add}" update="????" />
```

After the click on the 'add' button i need the update of the table (so i willsee the new element), but i dont want for some reasons that the nested panelGrid 'grid' is updated. I spent some day to find a solution with primefaces/jquery selector (particulary the ':not' selector) and I have tried many combination:
@(table :not(.grid)) @(#myTable :not(#grid)) but no way. 
I wonder if is possibile exclude a component from the update of the whole table.

Comment: This should do `@(#myTable :not(.grid))`.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/20080861 Understanding how exactly they work will help much in creating new selectors.

Comment: Thanks Tiny, but i had just tried that and doesn't works.

Comment: Thanks very much BalusC, your answer is very interesting as the others.I will try....

Answer (score 0):

@(form :not(.grid)

this is working 100% . i am using on my application.
it will update form and it will exclude grid.

add h:form in your code
<h:form>