# Referencing elements contained in a dynamic primefaces accordionPanel or dataGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

This question is directed towards the accordionPanel, but I believe it can be asked about similar dynamic renderers like dataGrid.

I would like to do some drawing on a canvas contained in each of the accordion's tabs. Similar to this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pklog/a7vrstv8/).

With this accorionPanel:

```
<form id="someForm">
<p:accordionPanel id="accordion" value="#{dataModel.values}" var="value">
    <p:tab id="entry" title="Entry - #{value}">
        <div id="layout">

            <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200">
            </canvas>

            <div id="foo" class="foo">#{value.data1}</div>
            <div id="bar" class="bar">#{value.data2}</div>
        </div>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
<p:remoteCommand name="updateAccordion" update="accordion"/>
</form>
```

When the html is rendered, foo and bar gain IDs similar to `:someForm:entry:0:foo`, `:someForm:entry:1:foo`, etc. How do I access these elements programmatically via javascript as I have show in the jsfiddle?

If there is an alternative path you think may suit me better, I am definitely open to trying it.

Here are a few other questions that I've read, but haven't been able to get enough information to help:

[How to do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work)

[How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression “foo” referenced from “bar”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)

The last link seems to have the best detail in it, but it seems like it may just not be possible to do what I want to do.

Your help is much appreciated and I look forward to gaining some new knowledge.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to come up with a solution and want to share for others that end up in a similar situation, but first would like to add some more details.

Rereading my question now I think I left out a couple of details with respect to how the acordionPanel was being updated. A backing bean maintains the state of what appears in each tab and when the bean is updated, it notifies the client via web socket that the state has changed. In this notification is also some information I need to draw on each tab beyond what the remote command will update. In processing the message off of the websocket, it will invoke the remote command above to update the accordionPanel.

Comment: I (think I) fail to really understand your problem. Is it that you do not know how to reference `:someForm:someTab:0:elementOfInterest` where the 0 differs in the panels?

Comment: That's right, I'm not sure how I can access those elements from JavaScript.

Comment: So 95 percent of your question is 'noise'? No wonder it took me 10 minutes to even try to understand. Please improve your question. Show code (in an [mcve] format) where this is used...

Comment: I edited the question so hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: In your code there is nothing related to 'update' or render, so both links you refer to are irrelevant. And your fiddle could contain the ***generated*** html from a real example. Then it would be way more clear. As it stands now, the answer is: `$('#someForm\:entry\:0\:foo')`...

Comment: Based on what I think I understand, the referenced links seemed the most relevant. I have a lot to learn and unfortunately most examples only cover the most basic of use cases. I do have a remoteCommand that is executed when the server passes word that state changed. I'll update the question momentarily.

Comment: You don't seem to be referencing the elements from an update or render but in plain jquery. Then the ***genereated*** html is relevant. Good luck. I already spend to much time in this question, sorry, hope others will help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised in the update, this is how I solved my problem.

My main issue was that I needed to be able to correlate the JSON data that was passed to the web socket telling the accordion to update. The JSON data contained a key, but the HTML on its own did not have a key. For this, I added to my div `.layout` a `data-key` attribute. With that attribute, I was able to now correlate each accordion tab with the JSON data. I also defined widgetVar on the accordion so that I could get a better handle on the tabs.

```html
<form id="someForm">
<p:accordionPanel id="accordion" value="#{dataModel.values}" var="value" widgetVar="accordion">
    <p:tab id="entry" title="Entry - #{value.title}">
        <div class="layout" data-key="#{value.key}">

            <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200">
            </canvas>

            <p:outputPanel id="foo" styleClass="foo">#{value.data1}</p:outputPanel>
            <p:outputPanel id="bar" styleClass="bar">#{value.data2}</p:outputPanel>
        </div>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
<p:remoteCommand name="updateAccordion" update="accordion" oncomplete="processUpdate()"/>
</form>
```

The when the JSON was processed after coming off the web socket, I saved the data so that it could be referenced by `processUpdate()` after the ajax call was complete.

This allowed `processUpdate()` to look something like this:

```js
// JSON data from original update message
var canvasData = ...;

function drawLine() {
  // ...
}

function processUpdate() {
  var tabs = PF('accordion').panels;
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var tab = $(tabs[i]);
    var key = tab.find('.layout').attr('data-key');

    for (var j = 0; j < canvasData.length; j++) {
      // Find the data that matches key
      if (canvasData[j].key == key) {
        var data = canvasData[jj];
        break;
      }
    }

    var canvas = $('#canvas');
    // With a handle on the tab, I could now ignore the `someForm:entry:1:`
    // prefix that made the element unique as I am now in the context of
    // one tab.
    var foo = tab.find('[id$=foo]');
    var bar = tab.find('[id$=bar]');
    drawLine(canvas, data, foo, bar);
  }
}
```

@Kukeltje - Thank you for trying to help me solve my problem.