# Exclude elements with specific Classes from Primefaces update

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Im sitting on a little Projekt, and im working on getting my internationalisation to work. But im encountering an issue with the ":not()" selector of primefaces "Update=""".

Buttons for language selection:

```
        <h:form styleClass="top_menu_item_inner">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 
           Language :      
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{userBean.changeLanguage('')}" value="German" update="@(.language_variable :not(.noUpdate))" />
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{userBean.changeLanguage('en')}" value="English" update="@(.language_variable :not(.noUpdate))" />

        </h:panelGrid> 
    </h:form>
```

Richfaces Tabpanel:

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="client">
            <rich:tab styleClass="language_variable" header="#{msg['general']}" id="tabset_tab_allgemein">
                <ui:include src="inc/veranstaltung_detail_allgemein.xhtml" />
            </rich:tab>
```

Element in "veranstaltung_detail_allgemein.xhtml":

```
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="veranstaltungen_detail_allgemein_kurzinfos noUpdate">
        #{msg['vak_number']}    <h:outputText styleClass="noUpdate" value="#{lectureBean.currentLecture.vakNumber}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
```

The problem is, that its updating every child of elements with the class "language_variable". But what im intentionally trying to do is, to exclude every child of an element with the class ="language_variable" that has the class "noUpdate". I hope you guys can help me. :)

Have a nice day.

Comment: You've a typo/syntax error in CSS selector. The `:xxx` pseudoselector should not be separated by a space.

Comment: @BalusC I am newbie in psuedoselector. Will  `@(.language_variable :div:not(.noUpdate))` work or OP should use `@(.language_variable:not(.noUpdate))`?

Comment: @Mahendran: see https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes, http://htmldog.com/guides/css and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20080861