# does jsf allow to exclude the child section when rendering its parent?

Tags: jsf

does jsf allow to exclude the child section when rendering its parent?

ex:

```
<h:panelGroup id="parent">
    <h:panelGroup id="child1">
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="child2">
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>

reRender="parent"
```

I called parent to on reRender. How will I exlcude "child1"? I am thinking that I have 100 child sections and I need to render 1-99. So instead of declaring child1-99 in reRender, I will just exclude child100 in the reRender. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So instead of declaring child1-99 in reRender, I will just exclude child100 in the reRender. Is it possible?*

No. At least not with `<a4j:ajax>` as you seem to be using, nor with `<f:ajax>`.

Your best bet is to dynamically compose render client IDs, so you don't need to hardcode all 99. This is easy to generate in a loop if they only differ in a numerical suffix such as `child1`, `child2`, `child3`, etc.

```
<a4j:ajax ... reRender="#{bean.clientIds}" />
```

In case you actually have PrimeFaces at hands too, make use of PFS to select them by CSS: [How do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work)