# JSF PrimeFaces ajax update excluding one component

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I got a form, that includes outputPanel that I need to update, excluding one of its component (it containts calendar, that resets after I call `update`, I want to prevent that)

```
<p:ajax update=":form1:outputPanel1 :not(form1:outputPanel1:nestedOutputPanel)"/>
```

But I have no idea how can I achieve something like this (above example is not working)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work)

Comment: Carefully read the PrimeFaces documentation and showcase. It's all in there...

Answer (score 4):

The PrimeFaces `update` attribute takes one or more expressions separated by a space (or comma). Normally (in plain JSF) those expressions are client IDs, but in PrimeFaces you can also use [selectors](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/selector.xhtml). A selector is executed and results in a list of client IDs to update. You could use a selector to select all the components that need to be updated and exclude the component you don't want to update.

You could add a style class to the component you want to exclude and use something like:

```
update="@(.parent :not(.exclude))"
```

As you can read in the top answer on the linked question, the `@(...)` selector will be used as a jQuery selector. So you can easily test selectors in your browser's JavaScript console as `$("...")`.

See also:

- [How do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work)

Comment: PF showcase has a ':not' example too: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/selector.xhtml