# Will Primefaces not automatically generate ID for html tag JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Today I found out an interesting thing with  tag in JSF. I got this point from a [BalusC's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20081310/2865414):

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.text1}" styleClass="myClass" />
    <p:commandButton value="Update" update="@(.myClass)" /> 
</h:form>
```

But the following example will work (note that assigning the form an ID is not necessary):

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputText id="myText" value="#{bean.text1}" styleClass="myClass" />
    <p:commandButton value="Update" update="@(.myClass)" /> 
</h:form>
```

It seems Primefaces will not generate an ID for *plain HTML tag*. I tried with several components, but still not sure. So, Is my conclusion correct? If so, why is this behaviour?

Comment: Effectively you state that using an `h:commandButton` instead of a PrimeFaces one makes it work (since the `p:commandButton` is the only 'PrimeFaces' related code in your post

Comment: Maybe no, mate. I thought h:commandButton don't have update element or partial update by selector

Comment: But is that 'selector update' relevant to the problem? (effectively it is as you most likely already know, but you could have investigated that and added that to the question)

Comment: Just confuse cause primefaces component has an Id, Html tag is not.  I thought they are the same mechanism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are asking why there is no ID attribute on your `<span>` element rendered by `<h:outputText value="#{bean.text1}" styleClass="myClass" />`:

By default, the `h:outputText` component rendered by `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TextRenderer` (in case of Mojarra) does not render an ID. Whether or not an ID is rendered is determined by `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.shouldWriteIdAttribute(UIComponent)` [right here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/2d22f78f81548c10f2c48a8fd8a04caa1628c0b3/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HtmlBasicRenderer.java#L641):

> ```
> /**
>      * @param component
>      *            the component of interest
>      *
>      * @return true if this renderer should render an id attribute.
>      */
>     protected boolean shouldWriteIdAttribute(UIComponent component) {
>
>         // By default we only write the id attribute if:
>         //
>         // - We have a non-auto-generated id, or...
>         // - We have client behaviors.
>         //
>         // We assume that if client behaviors are present, they
>         // may need access to the id (AjaxBehavior certainly does).
>
>         String id;
>         return (null != (id = component.getId()) && (!id.startsWith(UIViewRoot.UNIQUE_ID_PREFIX)
>                 || ((component instanceof ClientBehaviorHolder) && !((ClientBehaviorHolder) component).getClientBehaviors().isEmpty())));
> }
> ```

All of this is plain JSF and does not have any relation to primefaces.

Comment: You're right. For other HTML components, do they have an auto-generated id or not?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen: The source of Mojarra and MyFaces is open and freely accessible.

Comment: @Selaron: This answers why there is no id, but it sort of fails to address why the second example in the code works and the first one does not. i.e. why is the id relevant. Can I add that to your answer?

Comment: Was too fixed on the question title.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you